# Function overloading with Option Strict Off

Tags: vb.net

Is it a bad idea to use method overloading if option strict set to off?  Please see the code below.  There is a separate function for each datatype in .NET.  The class can handle Oracle and SQL server parameters:

```
Public Class clsParameterValues
        'Implements IDisposable

        Private paramValues(0) As DbParameter

        Public Function AssignParameterValues(ByVal strParameterName As String, ByVal strParameterValue As Long, ByVal intDatabaseType As Integer) As Integer
            Dim intArrayBound As Integer

            intArrayBound = UBound(paramValues)
            'If intArrayBound > 0 Then
            If paramValues(0) Is Nothing = False Then
                intArrayBound = intArrayBound + 1
                ReDim Preserve paramValues(intArrayBound)
            End If
            If intDatabaseType = 1 Then
                paramValues(intArrayBound) = New SqlParameter(strParameterName, strParameterValue)
            ElseIf intDatabaseType = 2 Then
                paramValues(intArrayBound) = New OracleParameter(strParameterName, strParameterValue)
                'paramValues(intArrayBound) = New OracleParameter(":" & strParameterName, OracleType.Int32)
                'paramValues(intArrayBound).Value = strParameterValue
            End If
            paramValues(intArrayBound).DbType = DbType.Int64
            Return intArrayBound
        End Function

        Public Function AssignParameterValues(ByVal strParameterName As String, ByVal strParameterValue As Integer, ByVal intDatabaseType As Integer) As Integer
            Dim intArrayBound As Integer

            intArrayBound = UBound(paramValues)
            'If intArrayBound > 0 Then
            If paramValues(0) Is Nothing = False Then
                intArrayBound = intArrayBound + 1
                ReDim Preserve paramValues(intArrayBound)
            End If
            If intDatabaseType = 1 Then
                paramValues(intArrayBound) = New SqlParameter(strParameterName, strParameterValue)
            ElseIf intDatabaseType = 2 Then
                paramValues(intArrayBound) = New OracleParameter(strParameterName, strParameterValue)
                'paramValues(intArrayBound) = New OracleParameter(":" & strParameterName, OracleType.Int32)
                'paramValues(intArrayBound).Value = strParameterValue
            End If
            paramValues(intArrayBound).DbType = DbType.Int32
            Return intArrayBound
        End Function

        Public Function AssignParameterValues(ByVal strParameterName As String, ByVal strParameterValue As String, ByVal intDatabaseType As Integer) As Integer
            Dim intArrayBound As Integer

            intArrayBound = UBound(paramValues)
            'If intArrayBound > 0 Then
            If paramValues(0) Is Nothing = False Then
                intArrayBound = intArrayBound + 1
                ReDim Preserve paramValues(intArrayBound)
            End If
            If intDatabaseType = 1 Then
                paramValues(intArrayBound) = New SqlParameter(strParameterName, strParameterValue)
            ElseIf intDatabaseType = 2 Then
                paramValues(intArrayBound) = New OracleParameter(strParameterName, strParameterValue)
                'paramValues(intArrayBound) = New OracleParameter(":" & strParameterName, OracleType.Int32)
                'paramValues(intArrayBound).Value = strParameterValue
            End If
            paramValues(intArrayBound).DbType = DbType.String
            Return intArrayBound
        End Function

        Public Function AssignParameterValues(ByVal strParameterName As String, ByVal strParameterValue As Date, ByVal intDatabaseType As Integer) As Integer
            Dim intArrayBound As Integer

            intArrayBound = UBound(paramValues)
            'If intArrayBound > 0 Then
            If paramValues(0) Is Nothing = False Then
                intArrayBound = intArrayBound + 1
                ReDim Preserve paramValues(intArrayBound)
            End If

            If intDatabaseType = 1 Then

                'paramValues(intArrayBound) = New SqlParameter(strParameterName, DateValue(strParameterValue))
                paramValues(intArrayBound) = New SqlParameter(strParameterName, strParameterValue)
            ElseIf intDatabaseType = 2 Then
                paramValues(intArrayBound) = New OracleParameter(strParameterName, strParameterValue)
                'paramValues(intArrayBound) = New OracleParameter(":" & strParameterName, OracleType.Int32)
                'paramValues(intArrayBound).Value = strParameterValue
            End If
            paramValues(intArrayBound).DbType = DbType.Date
            Return intArrayBound
        End Function

        Public Function AssignParameterValues(ByVal strParameterName As String, ByVal strParameterValue As Decimal, ByVal intDatabaseType As Integer) As Integer
            Dim intArrayBound As Integer

            intArrayBound = UBound(paramValues)
            'If intArrayBound > 0 Then
            If paramValues(0) Is Nothing = False Then
                intArrayBound = intArrayBound + 1
                ReDim Preserve paramValues(intArrayBound)
            End If

            If intDatabaseType = 1 Then

                paramValues(intArrayBound) = New SqlParameter(strParameterName, strParameterValue)
            ElseIf intDatabaseType = 2 Then
                paramValues(intArrayBound) = New OracleParameter(strParameterName, strParameterValue)
                'paramValues(intArrayBound) = New OracleParameter(":" & strParameterName, OracleType.Int32)
                'paramValues(intArrayBound).Value = strParameterValue
            End If
            paramValues(intArrayBound).DbType = DbType.Decimal
            Return intArrayBound
        End Function

        Public Function AssignParameterValues(ByVal strParameterName As String, ByVal strParameterValue As Boolean, ByVal intDatabaseType As Integer) As Integer
            Dim intArrayBound As Integer

            intArrayBound = UBound(paramValues)
            'If intArrayBound > 0 Then
            If paramValues(0) Is Nothing = False Then
                intArrayBound = intArrayBound + 1
                ReDim Preserve paramValues(intArrayBound)
            End If

            If intDatabaseType = 1 Then

                paramValues(intArrayBound) = New SqlParameter(strParameterName, strParameterValue)
            ElseIf intDatabaseType = 2 Then
                paramValues(intArrayBound) = New OracleParameter(strParameterName, strParameterValue)
                'paramValues(intArrayBound) = New OracleParameter(":" & strParameterName, OracleType.Int32)
                'paramValues(intArrayBound).Value = strParameterValue
            End If
            paramValues(intArrayBound).DbType = DbType.Boolean
            Return intArrayBound
        End Function

        Public Function getParameterValues() As DbParameter()
            Return paramValues
        End Function

    End Class
```

It is the responsibility of the caller to ensure the type is correct.  For example, pass a date type if you want to create a parameter of type date.  Is this reasonable?

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tb18a48w.aspx), `Option Strict` does not change the behaviour of the runtime when resolving overloaded functions / subs. Therefore (and because you stated that you cover every value type) it should not matter in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's definitely bad practice.  IMO (you should always have `Option Strict On`).

However, as long as you cover every case in terms of data types that you might expect, then your code will work.  As Stephan B stated, `Option Strict` does not change how the overloaded methods are resolved.  It simply allows for on-the-fly boxing/unboxing and type conversions when you try to use a variable of one type as though it were a different type (i.e., if you try to do math on a `String`).